# How to convert break point time series to 1 second resolution timeseries in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, time-series, breakpoints

I have a breakpoint time series (when monitored value changes a new timestamp is created), which is created using accuracy of 1 second (time stamps in form of yyyy:mm:dd:ss) and I'd like to change that time series to 1 second resolution time series.

Basically this means adding additional rows and timestamps in between breakpoint timestamps, and these new timestamps need to hold the last value of the monitored entity.

Example
Breakpoint time series
[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VhEX.png)

Wanted 1 second res time series
[1 second res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH24J.png)

etc. I hope you get the idea.

Problem is that I don't know how to get started with this issue, I haven't been able to find that many similar cases from the archives.

What could be a good way of approaching this type of dilemma, and how to implement the described solution as a code for VBA?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
BR
Muje

EDIT:
I have created a short script that can add missing rows and duplicate the value above to this new row. However I am still struggling with cases where there is more than 1 second missing from the break point time series. Code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub BP_to_sec()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test")

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowStep As Long

Dim S As Double
S = (1 / 86400)

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For RowStep = LastRow To 3 Step -1
   If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & RowStep)) Then
     If (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep)) > (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep - 1)) + S)) Then
       Range("A" & RowStep).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(RowStep, 1).Value = Cells(RowStep - 1, 1).Value + S
        Cells(RowStep, 2).Value = Cells(RowStep - 1, 2).Value
     End If
   End If
 Next

MsgBox ("Sorted")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub BP_to_sec()
        
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test")
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim RowStep As Long
        
        Dim S As Double
        S = (1 / 86400)
        
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RowStep = LastRow
        Do While RowStep > 3
            If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & RowStep)) Then
                If (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep)) - (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep - 1)) + S)) > S Then
                    Range("A" & RowStep).EntireRow.Insert
                    Cells(RowStep, 1).Value = Cells(RowStep + 1, 1).Value - S
                    Cells(RowStep, 2).Value = Cells(RowStep - 1, 2).Value
                    RowStep = RowStep + 1
                End If
            End If
            RowStep = RowStep - 1
        Loop
        
        MsgBox ("Sorted")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I posted a solution by my self as well, It seems that the approach is more or less the same. Haven't tested your version but should be ok by a quick glance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution by my self as well! I'll post it here if someone finds this exact same problem.

```
Option Explicit
Sub BP_to_sec1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Test")

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim RowStep As Integer
Dim FillRow As Integer

Dim S As Double
Dim SS As Double
S = (1 / 86400)     ' 1 sec
SS = (1.2 / 86400)  ' 1.2 sec dif

Dim X As Integer

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 For RowStep = LastRow To 3 Step -1
   If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & RowStep)) Then
     If (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep)) > (CDate(Range("A" & RowStep - 1)) + SS)) Then
        X = ((Second((Range("A" & RowStep))) - (Second(Range("A" & RowStep - 1)))))
        Range("A" & RowStep).EntireRow.Offset(0).Resize(X - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
         If X > 0 Then
            For FillRow = RowStep To (RowStep + (X - 2)) Step 1
                Range("A" & FillRow).Value = Range("A" & (FillRow - 1)).Value + S
                Range("B" & FillRow, "AA" & FillRow).Value = Range("B" & (FillRow - 1), "AA" & (FillRow - 1)).Value
            Next
         End If
     End If
   End If
 Next

MsgBox ("Sorted")

End Sub
```

As a comment, on this solution I have wider range of data in use, reaching all the way to column "AA", hence I made the edit to copy all data below, except of course the timestamp, which is added 1s.

Big thanks also to @h2so4 for your answer, I havent tested but it seems that we are using same elements. My version is also a bit more messy...

Any comments are more than welcome!

Thanks for the help!
BR
Muje

Comment: A problem found in my own code. I try to add the missing amount of rows between two datapoints and then fill in the missing information, but it seems that when approaching this problem as I have, the code breaks in situation where previous datapoint has time xx:04:57 and next datapoint has time xx:05:01, as now the difference between "seconds" is -56. Any clues on sorting this?

Comment: I'll be commenting this on my own. Solution is (as usual) to ditch all time related functions and use 86400 to convert dates to seconds, I replaced some rows on my initial code as follows: X = (((Range("A" & RowStep).Value) * 86400) - ((Range("A" & RowStep - 1).Value) * 86400))